# Limitar consulta INNER JOIN a somente um ID

Tags: sql

**Estou realizando a seguinte consulta:**

```
SELECT enquete.image, 
       enquete.status      AS status_enquete, 
       enquete.id          AS id_enquete, 
       enquete.title       AS titulo_enquete, 
       perguntas.id        AS id_pergunta, 
       perguntas.title     AS titulo_pergunta
FROM   obs_survey_questions AS perguntas 
       INNER JOIN obs_survey AS enquete 
               ON enquete.id = perguntas.survey_id 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id 
                   FROM   obs_survey 
                   GROUP  BY id) b 
               ON perguntas.survey_id = b.id 
WHERE  status = 1 
GROUP  BY id_pergunta
```

**E recebendo o seguinte resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> No entanto, meu objetivo é que venha somente de UMA **ID_ENQUETE**, mas não sei porque sempre vem duas, no caso acima, a 14 e a 1.

Comment: indica qual ID (id_enquete) da enquete você quer retornar somente e depois faz uso de um GROUP BY id_enquete.

Comment: Mas qual ID deveria ser devolvido? Apenas quer que retorne um? Qual o objetivo da consulta? Tem de detalhar mais a sua questão, senão fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: @JoãoMartins O problema é que ta vindo todas as enquetes com status 1, mas eu quero somente a primeira ativa e suas respectivas perguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente desta forma (isto se percebi bem o que pretende):

```
SELECT      E.image
        ,   E.status    AS status_enquete
        ,   E.id        AS id_enquete
        ,   E.title     AS titulo_enquete
        ,   P.id        AS id_pergunta
        ,   P.title     AS titulo_pergunta
FROM        obs_survey_questions    P 
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      TOP 1 image
                        ,   status
                        ,   id
                        ,   title
                FROM        obs_survey
                ORDER BY    id
            )                       E ON E.id = P.survey_id 
GROUP BY    P.id_pergunta
```

Basicamente vai buscar o primeiro `ID`, ordenado por essa mesma coluna, e junta com a tabela `obs_survey_questions`.

Comment: Era isto mesmo. perfeito.

Answer (score 1):

ja que não especificou um survey_id no Where pode usar o Top:

```
'SELECT TOP 1 enquete.image, 
   enquete.status      AS status_enquete, 
   enquete.id          AS id_enquete, 
   enquete.title       AS titulo_enquete, 
   perguntas.id        AS id_pergunta, 
   perguntas.title     AS titulo_pergunta
FROM   obs_survey_questions AS perguntas 
   INNER JOIN obs_survey AS enquete 
           ON enquete.id = perguntas.survey_id 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT id 
               FROM   obs_survey 
               GROUP  BY id) b 
           ON perguntas.survey_id = b.id 
   WHERE  status = 1 
   GROUP  BY id_pergunta '
```

Comment: Não deu certo, mano